# Problems with last row in Tlistview Delphi

Tags: listview, delphi

I have a ListView with some data and it works fine except when i`m trying to get the data from the last row, in that case it returns random data.

I have a function where I add the objects (object list from a class) to the list view, and after onother one for delete the data from database and populate again the list view.

//Here I populate the list view

```
procedure TFrameEinExpression.Fill_Rows;
var
  itm : TFormulaFeatures;
  i : integer;
begin
  lvModels.Clear;
   EinExpression.LoadFeatureList;

  if (not Assigned(EinExpression)) or (EinExpression.FeatureList.Count = 0)  then
    Exit;
  lvModels.Items.BeginUpdate;

  try
    for i := 0 to EinExpression.FeatureList.Count - 1  do
      with lvModels.Items.Add do
        begin
          itm := TFormulaFeatures(EinExpression.FeatureList.Items[i]);
          Data := TFormulaFeatures(EinExpression.FeatureList.Items[i]);
          Caption := IntToStr(itm.Posicion);
          SubItems.Add(BoolToStr(itm.Presencia, True));
          SubItems.Add(itm.Descripcion);
          SubItems.Add(IntToStr(itm.Idcaract1));
        end;
  finally
    lvModels.Items.EndUpdate;
    if Assigned(itm) then
      itm.Free;
  end;
end;



//Here I perform the action (it works fine except for the last row)


if (Assigned (lvModels.Selected)) and (Assigned (lvModels.Selected.Data)) then

//This already doesn't have anything inside
showmessage('Desc :'+ TFormulaFeatures(lvModels.Selected.Data).Descripcion);

  begin
    BDMultiEP.SQLExecute('DELETE from [EXPRESSION] WHERE (idcaract=:Z) AND 
    (idcaract1=:Y)', [EinExpression.IDCARACT,
     TFormulaFeatures(lvModels.Selected.Data).IDCARACT1]);
  end;


//after this i take the values from the DB to the class and populate the List View again.
LoadFeatureList;
Fill_Rows;
```

In the showmessage (for test) I have the field description but when is the last one i dont have anything.

Comment: This line looks suspicious: `if Assigned(itm) then itm.Free;`

Comment: @LURD: Indeed. There should be no need to call `itm.Free` as it is not an owning reference.

Comment: @LURD: probably the cause of the error (itm points to last item, and if that is freed --> kaboom!). Please post that as answer. And I wonder what Data is supposed to do. ISTM: nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line `if Assigned(itm) then itm.Free;` frees the last item of `EinExpression.FeatureList`.

Since `itm` is **not** responsible for the lifetime of that object, this is the most probable cause of the missing data in the last list item.

Remove that line.